# Starting Linux from power off at predetermined time (and executing command)?

Tags: linux-mint, hardware, scheduling

To put it simply, I'm trying to use my computer as an alarm clock. It's slightly old and noisy, so I'd like it to start from power off at a scheduled time and then execute a command, such as playing an MP3 file. I'm running Linux Mint Nadia. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You can send a magic packet to the computers MAC address. **Notice** that you need to enable this in your Bios.

Then you can install `wakeonlan` via `apt-get` and use the following command to "wake" your system:

```
wakeonlan 01:02:03:04:05:06
```

For your concern you need another machine to send this packet. For this there are several wake on lan services you can find via google, where you can set a specific time.

Comment: Sometimes the magic packet doesn't work. Your system must support Wake on Lan (WOL). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN

Answer (score 2):

From the MythTV's [ACPI Wakeup wiki article](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/ACPI_Wakeup).

*excerpt*

> #### Your options
>
> 1. Hardware timer switch - a cheap power switch and a simple cron job to shutdown the machine can do the job
> 2. Wake on LAN - have another machine on your network wake your MythTV machine. ([See the "Wake on LAN" MythTV HowTo](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN))
> 3. Use the real time clock (RTC) - most machines (manufactured in 2000 or later) have the ability to use the RTC for time-controlled wakeup - this option is the subject of this HowTo

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a tool called [rtcwake](http://linux.die.net/man/8/rtcwake). It allows you to suspend your system and specify a specific wake up time. You can then set up a cronjob to play your song at a specified time.

I found a nice example [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/wake-cron.html):

> If I wanted my machine to sleep overnight, wake for a short
>   maintenance, go to sleep again and wake early in the morning, I would
>   have four crons running. The first, to synchronize the OS clock with
>   UTC (via ntp). The second, to synchronize hardware clock with UTC. The
>   third, to put the machine to sleep every evening, using rtcwake and
>   specify the exact moment when it should wake up later. The fourth cron
>   would run a few minutes after the machine wakes and do whatever needs
>   to be done. After all the tasks are complete, it would sleep the
>   machine once more and make it wake up in the morning.

So, in your case, you would set it up to turn the machine on at a couple of minutes before the time you want your alarm to sound and then, set up a cronjob that runs your alarm.

First, suspend your computer and set it to turn on at a specific time, say 9 am. To do this, you need to translate "Tomorrow, 9 am" to [UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), seconds since the epoch. You can do this with `date`:

```
$ date -d "tomorrow 9 am" +%s
1393228800
```

Combine that with `rtcwake` to have your ciomputer sleep now and wake at 9 am tomorrow:

```
$ rtcwake -m mem -t $(date -d "tomorrow 9 am" +%s)
```

So, create a crontab to play your mp3 at 9:05 (run `crontab -e` and paste this line into the file that opens):

```
05 09 * * * vlc /home/terdon/Music/mysong.mp3
```

Now, before going to sleep, just turn off the computer with the `rtcwake` command above and it will automatically turn on next morning at 9 and 5 minutes later will start playing your song.